# How to define a new xkb type and make it the defaul for a specific layout?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am a Java programmer and I often need to write lots of text in Hungarian, German or Slovak. Quite often, I have to do all simultaneously, which makes constantly switching between different layouts impractical. Luckily, the Hungarian keyboard layout already has most of the symbols required for everything, and the rest can be added easily by changing the relevant xkb symbols file.

This, however, hides many of the necessary characters behind the 3rd level. One problem I have not been able to solve yet is, defining the way that the 3rd level can be accessed. Ideally, I would want to mimic the same behaviour that windows has, where 3rd level can be accessed either by pressing the Left Alt + Ctrl together or by pressing the Right Alt (AltGr) key. Unfortunately, on Ubuntu 22.04, which we use in the company, this can only be done using the Right Alt (AltGr) key. Gnome tweaks has the option to change the default to various other keys, but none of them do what I want.

I have found a similar related question: [how to bind AltGr to <Ctrl> + <Alt>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157834/how-to-bind-altgr-to-ctrl-alt) where the answers indicate that this can be done by creating a new xkb type, but nobody ended up sharing their code, and I cannot reliably replicate the last step of setting the new xkb type as a default for my layout, which is required to make the whole thing work.

- I have started by editing my `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/hu` file. By changing the `key <AE...` entries inside the relevant `xkb_symbols "102_qwerty_comma_dead"` section, I was able to add some additional characters to the 3rd level.
- Then, I added the definition for the new xkb type from the question above to my `/usr/share/X11/xkb/types/basic` file:

```
   default xkb_types "basic" {
           ...
           type "CA_to_L3" {
           modifiers = Control+Alt+Shift;
           map[None] = Level1;
           map[Shift] = Level2;
           map[Control+Alt] = Level3;
           map[Control+Alt+Shift] = Level4;
           level_name[Level1] = "Base";
           level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
           level_name[Level3] = "Alt Base";
           level_name[Level4] = "Shift Alt";
           };
           ...
   };
```

- Finally, I have tried adding `key.type="CA_to_L3";` to both the `xkb_symbols "def_common" {...}` and `xkb_symbols "102_qwerty_comma_dead" {...}` sections of my `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/hu` file, but it did not do what I was expecting it to do, it just disabled 3rd level altogether.
- I have also tried the same thing with `key.type[Group1]="CA_to_L3";`, because a similar statement is used in other places in the same file, but it resulted in the same behaviour.

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong?
By running: `$ setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`
I get:

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     hu,gb,sk,gb
variant:    102_qwerty_comma_dead,,qwerty,
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwertz)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+hu(102_qwerty_comma_dead)+gb:2+sk(qwerty):3+gb:4+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwertz)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+hu(102_qwerty_comma_dead)+gb:2+sk(qwerty):3+gb:4+inet(evdev)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

This shows that the xkb type complete is loaded up, which includes within itself the xkb type basic, yet I still do not get the defined functionality.